# numberOfRowsInSection returns more than 0; cellForRowAtIndexPath still not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I notice this problem is very common and there are alot of posts about it but none of the solutions i tried so far worked.

So I have a delegate method that updates the datasource: NSArray * posts and reload the table view. I am positive that posts is updated before the reload call because i logged it.

It calls the numberOfRowInSection method and [posts count] returns more than 0 every time. but the cellForRowAtIndexPath is still not called.

the tableview is created from the IB and content is currently shows content and the cells before the reload. i need one of the cells content to be updated but it doesnt because cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called.

This only happens for the delegate method.

I tried making the reload call on the main thread using both gcd and perform selectorOnMainThread still no go.

Any ideas what maybe causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Is you tableview's height >0 ? Is it added to your view ?

Comment: Yes i logged the tableview inside numberOf.. method and the frame is good

Comment: Add some code for better understanding..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate in your .h and connected the tableview delegate, data source and cellindentifier Cell in .xib.

have you registered your cell ?

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: yes delegates and datasource are set from in the IB and cells are showing content i just needed to update one cell. Sorry i should have explained that in the question. I just edited

Comment: Are you sure you are updating your NSArray *posts array before doing the reload? Also, I'm assuming you are setting numberOfRowsInSection via return [posts count];

Comment: So the problem is you want to reload cell ? but have you check if the cell you want to change is this one u got ?
Remember that the cell is reusableview. In the moment you try to edit current cell She can be another one. (System use this view to present other) but addres of reusableview is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Load your tableView in method

```
awakeFromNib
```

this solved my problem.